# Need help creating a persistent bottom navigation bar in inner pages using auto_route: ^7.4.0 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, auto-route

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project and I'm facing an issue regarding the implementation of a persistent bottom navigation bar using auto_route: ^7.4.0 in my Flutter application. I've searched extensively for a solution but haven't found anything that addresses my specific requirement.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want to create a bottom navigation bar that remains persistent across multiple pages or screens in my app. I have already implemented the navigation using auto_route: ^7.4.0, which is working well for navigating between screens. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to keep the bottom navigation bar visible and interactive when switching between pages.

Here are some relevant details about my setup:

Flutter version: 3.10
auto_route version: ^7.4.0
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction or provide a code example demonstrating how to achieve a persistent bottom navigation bar using auto_route: ^7.4.0. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to consider would be highly valuable.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.
**My Tab page**

```
AutoTabsScaffold(
        routes: [
          const HomeRoute(),
          SearchRoute(),
          const CoursesRoute(),
          const ProfileRoute()
        ],
        bottomNavigationBuilder: (_,tabsRouter) {
          //final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              if (tabsRouter.activeIndex != 0) {
                if (backStack.isNotEmpty) {
                  final previousIndex = backStack.removeLast();
                  tabsRouter.setActiveIndex(previousIndex);
                  return false; // Prevent the app from closing
                }
                return true;
              }
              backStack.clear();
              return true;
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 72,
              decoration: buildYellowBoxDecoration(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: buildGreenBoxDecoration(),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                      child: buildBottomNavigationBar(
                          tabsRouter,
                          backStack,
                          homeIcon,
                          homeIconActive,
                          searchIcon,
                          searchIconActive,
                          coursesIcon,
                          coursesIconActive,
                          profileIcon,
                          profileIconActive),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        // bottomNavigationBuilder: (context, tabsRouter) {
        //     return   NumberOneAppBottomBarWidget( tabsRouter: tabsRouter,);
        //   }

        );
```

**My router page**

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
    //login and onBoarding
    AutoRoute(
      page: SplashRoute.page,
      path: "/splash",
    ),
    AutoRoute(page: DashBoardRoute.page, path: "/", guards: [AuthGuard()]),
    AutoRoute(
        page: RegistrationSuccessfulRoute.page,
        path: "/registration_successful"),
    AutoRoute(page: RegistrationRoute.page, path: "/registration"),
    AutoRoute(page: LoginRoute.page, path: "/loginPage"),
    AutoRoute(page: VerifyOtpRoute.page, path: "/verifyOtp"),
    AutoRoute(page: LanguageSelectionRoute.page, path: "/languageSelect"),
    AutoRoute(
        page: OnBoardSelectEntrepreneurRoute.page,
        path: "/onboard_select_entrepreneur"),
    AutoRoute(
        page: OnBoardPreparingDataRoute.page, path: "/onboard_prepare_data"),

    AutoRoute(page: NotificationRoute.page, path: "/notifications"),
    AutoRoute(page: CourseDetailRoute.page, path: "/course_detail"),
    AutoRoute(page: VideoBuilderRoute.page, path: "/video_player/:arguments"),
    //AutoRoute(page: VideoPlayRoute.page, path: "/video_player_appinio"),

    AutoRoute(page: BundleCourseRoute.page, path: "/bundle_course_page"),

    //BottomNavigation
    AutoRoute(page: HomeTabRoute.page, path: "/", children: [
      CustomRoute(page: HomeRoute.page, path: "home_page",
      children: [
        AutoRoute(page: VideoPlayRoute.page, path: "course_details_page/:arguments"),
      ]),
      CustomRoute(page: SearchRoute.page, path: "search_route"),
      CustomRoute(page: ProfileRoute.page, path: "profile_route"),
      CustomRoute(page: CoursesRoute.page, path: "courses_route"),
    ]),
    //Admin Pages
    AutoRoute(page: AdminCourseListRoute.page, path: "/admin_course_list"),
    AutoRoute(page: AdminAddLessonRoute.page, path: "/admin_add_lesson_page"),
    AutoRoute(page: AdminAddCourseRoute.page, path: "/admin_add_course_page"),

    RedirectRoute(path: '*', redirectTo: '/'),
  ];
}
```

I've explored different approaches, including using a global widget for the bottom navigation bar, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I'm unsure if I'm missing something or if there's a specific configuration I need to apply to make it work.

Comment: did you find the solution? i am also looking for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested routes for the bottom navigation bar to persist. Read more here : https://pub.dev/documentation/auto_route/latest/#nested-navigation

Also keep in mind while using nested routes that you need to create a seprate dummy tab route and include routes related to that tab inside it. This took up a lot of my time to fix. Hope it helps.

More context here : https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1654#issuecomment-1976601887 .

Also you can use the `meta` property to be able to hide and show the bottom nav bar.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35831952)